# How to allow the user can access his home page after longing in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new one to asp.net mvc4. Now i am doing Login page. Login is working fine. Link for login is :59523/Login and //:59523/Admin/ListUsers  , //:59523/Login/Changepassword these are the some other links.
   If i use //:59523/Admin/ListUsers this link in address bar, it is directly redirecting into that page before logging in . How to restrict a user from it. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

This is my controller code for login:

```
[HttpGet]

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //Verifying the User Name and Password using the Method
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogIn(Tbl_Users user, FormCollection remember)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `Authorize` attribute on your controller action level or the controller level to restrict access as follows:

**Action**

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ListUsers()
{
   ...
}
```

**Controller**

```
[Authorize]
public class AdminController : Controller
{

  ...

}
```

More info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx